# Not getting ping response on CentOS server hosted with DigitalOcean

Tags: centos, ping

I have a CentOS server with DigitalOcean , i am trying to ping "1c-bitrix.ru" , i am getting the following `PING 1c-bitrix.ru (46.235.53.93) 56(84) bytes of data.` but there is no response.

I tried the same from my Mac and its working properly. My IPTables are as follows

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**Update

I ran a traceroute on 1c-bitrix.ru and see the packets are getting dropped in middle and not reaching destination. I did the same from other computer and it works fine , so there is no issue on the destination side.

[image: Traceroute]

Comment: Please show the firewall on the other host.

Comment: @MichaelHampton the host is a simple website, i dont have control over the host. I am using a application called Bitrix, it uses 1c-bitrix.ru for updating. Its not updating cause of this issuse.

Comment: Maybe they have banned your IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your firewall to allow incoming and outgoing ICMP traffic.

Here's an example using iptables:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -s $YOUR_SERVER_IP -d 0/0 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -s 0/0 -d $YOUR_SERVER_IP -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

The icmp type number is part of the protocol. 0 is for echo reply and 8 is echo request.

Comment: I have removed all the firewalls , i even tried to stop the firewalld, still its not working..

Comment: Do DigitalOcean have specific requirement for enabling ping/icmp? Maybe contact them?

Comment: nothing specify , they do have firewall setting similar to AWS , but i am not using it. The confusing part is only this site is not accessible rest all works...